# Javascript: How do I check mixed user input against an array of data objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, for-loop

I am building a calculator app and am stuck at the part where I check the values chosen by the user against the data set of plans I have on the server.

I am using four data sliders that look like this:

[image]

Every time the user slides the slider, I send back values to my script for validation and checking.

Now here is the static data set of values I am checking the user's input against:

```
plandata.data = [

            {       

                id: 'small',

                from: {
                    cpu: 1,
                    ram: 1,
                    hd: 40,
                    bw: 10
                },

                to: {
                    cpu: 2,
                    ram: 2,
                    hd: 500,
                    bw: 500
                },

                price: {
                    linux: 3490,
                    windows: 4190
                }

            },


            {

                id: 'medium',

                from: {
                    cpu: 2,
                    ram: 2,
                    hd: 40,
                    bw: 20
                },

                to: {
                    cpu: 4,
                    ram: 4,
                    hd: 500,
                    bw: 500
                },

                price: {
                    linux: 5600,
                    windows: 6300
                }

            },
  ...three more plans like this
```

Now what I want to do is:

- loop over the plan data and check which plan the user has chosen: Is it `small`, `medium`, `large` etc
- throw an error and reset the slider if the values are out of valid range i.e. they should be between the `from` and `to` range.
- if plan is correct, then get the price of that plan

I am stuck on the first step right now. Here is my code:

```
checkPlaninRange = function(cpuVal, ramVal, hdVal, bwVal) {
                    _.each(pdata, function(plan){

            if (cpuVal >= plan.from.cpu && cpuVal < plan.to.cpu 
                     && ramVal >= plan.from.ram && ramVal < plan.to.ram
                     && hdVal >= plan.from.hd && hdVal < plan.to.hd
                     && bwVal >= plan.from.bw && bwVal < plan.to.bw
                    ) 
            {
                console.log(plan.id, 'Plan Found');
            } else {
                console.log('plan not found');
            };

        });

};
```

The problem is: I am getting mixed results

```
plan not found plan.js:41
medium Plan Found plan.js:39

plan not found plan.js:41
medium Plan Found plan.js:39

plan not found plan.js:41
medium Plan Found plan.js:39

plan not found plan.js:41
medium Plan Found plan.js:39

plan not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to wrap my head around looping through the plan data and getting the right plan. Please help.

Comment: Either through the debugger or through console.log you should validate the parameter values in your checkPlaninRange function. Post those here if you still do not see why the logic is failing. I suspect there is something nonobvious in your big logic check there. It may help to break that down into 4 if statements (not long term, but just for debugger purposes).

Comment: @EricLaForce, the parameters passed into the function are the same values that you see chosen in the interface. As for the debugger statement, see the last five lines of code in my question - that is chrome console output.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cpuVal >= plan.from.cpu && cpuVal <= plan.to.cpu 
                 && ramVal >= plan.from.ram && ramVal <= plan.to.ram
                 && hdVal >= plan.from.hd && hdVal <= plan.to.hd
                 && bwVal >= plan.from.bw && bwVal <= plan.to.bw
                )
```

I guess you want AND and not OR

Comment: I think you are right but now I am getting a mix of valid and invalid values. What should I do next to capture the right plan. Valid User input has to fall between only one of these ranges.

Comment: Looking at your data types Limit it either on to value or from value i.e. make it < plan.to.cpu and not <= as in that case you will have overlap

Comment: should I also do the same for `>=`?

Comment: nope neither of these things are working - I am just not getting the right plan. Do you think the data that has been given to me is flawed in some way?

Comment: no, looking at the data no. See what values you want in the plan and you will figure it out